# Relation between wave number and wave vector?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

What is the relation between wave number and wave vector?

I've been self-studying wavefunctions as part of an intro into Quantum Mechanics. However, the textbooks, sites, and videos that I've seen do not really explain the correlation, other than that wavenumber is the magnitude of the wavevector. There seems to not be any visual anywhere for a wavevector; from my understanding, it is a vector connecting to maxima, minima, equilibrium points, etc, essentially graphing the period/frequency with a vector. Is this true?

Comment: Wikipedia : "In physics, a wave vector (also spelled wavevector) is a vector which helps describe a wave. Like any vector, it has a magnitude and direction, both of which are important: Its magnitude is either the wavenumber or angular wavenumber of the wave (inversely proportional to the wavelength), and its direction is ordinarily the direction of wave propagation (but not always, see below)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction of the wavevector represents the direction in which the wave is propagating in. The phase variation for a plane wave will always be $\frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}$.

Comment: So it's defined as a vector in the direction of the propagation with magnitude k, the wavenumber??

Comment: @Shadow Sniper: Yes, for plane waves.

Answer (score 1):

The wave vector is normal to the surfaces of constant phase ('wave fronts') with a length inversely proportional to wavelength. It corresponds to wave momentum, and is one way to describe wave propagation (another one is energy flux, which, in case of electromagnetic waves, is given by the Poynting vector; depending on the medium, wave and Poynting vector need not align necessarily).